# Linq query "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: linq

I have 2 simple webservice methods that query an XML document (stored in HTTP cache) that I am querying via javascript. The `GetCitiesForAffiliate()` method is throwing a NullReferenceException on the "select new" line when I pass in one perfectly valid item of data for the aff parameter. It works fine for other data in the aff parameter. The other method also works fine, even with the same aff parameter that causes the other method to bomb out.

I just validated the XML that I am querying. Both methods just return an empty json string when I pass in an aff that doesn't exist, which is OK. What should I look at that might be wrong?

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetCitiesForAffiliate(string aff)
    {
        LocationService loc = new LocationService();
        var query = (from center in loc.centersXml.Descendants("Center")
                     where center.Element("ServiceArea").Value.Equals(aff)
                     select new {
                         City = center.Element("City").Value
                     }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.City);

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = serializer.Serialize(query);

        return json;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetCentersForAffiliateCity(string aff, string city)
    {
        LocationService loc = new LocationService();
        var query = (from center in loc.centersXml.Descendants("Center")
                     where center.Element("ServiceArea").Value.Equals(aff) && center.Element("City").Value.Equals(city)
                     select new { 
                         ID = center.Element("ID").Value,
                         Name = center.Element("Name").Value 
                     }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Name);

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = serializer.Serialize(query);

        return json;
    }
```

Comment: `center.Element("City")` could be null (meaning there is no `City` element).

Comment: OMG I found one that was blank just for "aff=26". FML

Comment: PS @DStanley I'll have to go read up on how to gracefully handle this error but if you have any links let me know. Thanks!!

Comment: I've found a topic on MSDN dealing with System.NullReferenceException. Maybe someone needs some advice on how to handle it. You'll find it here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2011/05/04/linq-to-xml-handling-blank-or-no-element-and-attribute/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If some of your nodes are missing a City element, you have some choices, depending on what output you want:

1) Add a check to see if the `City` element is `null`:

```
City = (center.Element("City") == null ? null : center.Element("City").Value)
```

2) Add where clause to ignore elements with a null city:

```
where center.Element("ServiceArea").Value.Equals(aff) 
    and center.Element("City") != null
```