# LINQ Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq Query to get some data from a Data table `dt_Customers`. I am using following code:

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection =
                   from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
                   let zip = company.Field<string>("ZIP")
                   where ((zip != null) && zip.StartsWith("" + 4 + "") || zip.StartsWith("" + 5 + ""))
                   select company;
```

In Where clause (`where ((zip != null) && zip.StartsWith("" + 4 + "") || zip.StartsWith("" + 5 + ""))`) I am getting this error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

I read this post [Linq query "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591440/linq-query-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) and 
[LINQ Object Referance not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957355/linq-object-referance-not-set)

After this I updated Where clause and put a check `(zip != null)` But still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the brackets like this:

```
 where zip != null && (zip.StartsWith("" + postalcodefrom + "") || 
                        zip.StartsWith("" + postalcodeto + ""))
```

Also instead of checking `null`, you need to figure out why `zip` is *null*

Comment: Why do you think it is necessary to figure out why `zip` is null?

Comment: @Tim maybe he typed the wrong column name and all zip's are becoming null?

Comment: @Tim: Maybe it isn't, but it did sound as if zip being null had surprised him and the check was a kludge.

Answer (score 1):

AND binds stronger than OR - so try this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection =
                   from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
                   let zip = company.Field<string>("ZIP")
                   where (zip != null && (zip.StartsWith(postalcodefrom) 
                                          || zip.StartsWith(postalcodeto)))
                   select company;
```